# Certificate in Pending state in AWS Certificate Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cname, aws-certificate-manager

Our project is deployed on Elastic Beanstalk and I want to run this on HTTPs. I created my certificate on AWS Certificate Manager and choose DNS verification option. I added provided data in my Godaddy DNS records. Below is my sample data

```
Domain Name | Record Name | Record Type | Record Value 

example.com | _8046ecb910c52234234234234232ecae.example.com. | CNAME | _81b05686qweerttcxsaxasdadas5a566.tljzshvwok.acm-validations.aws. 

*.example.com | _8046ecb910c52234234234234232ecae.example.com. | CNAME |  _81b05686qweerttcxsaxasdadas5a566.tljzshvwok.acm-validations.aws.
```

AWS has given my two records for example.com and *.example.com but both records are same. So I added one CNAME record in Godaddy DNS entries. I waited for three days and my certificate was still in pending state which in the end expired. I created a new one and I have been waiting for 24 hours and it is still in pending state. I cannot use Email verification method as I am not owner of this domain.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An apparently common error is to paste the entire hostname into a box that does not expect an FQDN, thus creating a record that actually looks like this in DNS (though you may not observe it this way on the screen):

```
_8046ecb910c52234234234234232ecae.example.com.example.com
```

For the "hostname," just use `_8046ecb910c52234234234234232ecae` when creating the record.

After creating it, use `dig` or `nslookup` to verify that it resolves as expected.

Comment: I put `.` in the end after my server address. Does that make any difference.? Or I should remove server address?

Comment: The correct answer is highly dependent on the UI of the DNS host.  Did you try querying your record with `dig`?  Either you get the right result, get the wrong result, or get no result, and how to proceed depends on what you have now.  Without knowing the actual domain you are using, it's difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. How to use `dig` for this purpose?

Answer (score 12):

I had similar issue with AWS certificate in  'Pending validation' state for quite some time. After few tries I finally got it to get in 'Success' state. It might vary by domain registrar , in my case it was NameCheap.

Refer the screenshots from AWS ACM and NameCheap to follow the step that got it working for me:

[image: DNS record validation]

Answer (score 7):

I also had this issue and waited a day but still Pending Validation. I followed answers here but still got confused and Pending Validation so I decided to share the step by step of what worked for me in NameCheap.

In AWS:

1. Export the DNS configuration file. It will have something like this.

```
    Domain Name,Record Name,Record Type,Record Value
    mysite.io,_beocc4be975f27599f5d77f87af84321.mysite.io.,CNAME,_6ae531c5dad6c5ceeefd65a73d532881.dumrqilasr.acm-validations.aws.
```

In NameCheap:

2. Choose "Domain" tab > NameServers - Choose NameCheap Basic DNS
3. Choose "Advanced DNS" tab > Host Records
4. Under Type, choose "CNAME record"
5. Under Host, use the value in "Record Name". Do not include the domain name.

```
    _beocc4be975f27599f5d77f87af84321.
```

6. Under Value, use the value in "Record Value". Copy everything.

```
    _6ae531c5dad6c5ceeefd65a73d532881.dumrqilasr.acm-validations.aws.
```

7. Under TTL, choose "Automatic"
8. Save the settings by clicking the check icon right beside TTL.

In AWS:

9. Refresh the AWS Certificate Manager after 2-5 minutes. It should only take a few minutes for Amazon status to change from Pending Validation to Issued.

Comment: It _should_ only take a few minutes, but occasionally it can take as long as an hour or two.  I just waited 70 minutes for my certificate to be approved.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same pending-forever issue with the domain which I registered at  [Freenom](https://www.freenom.com/en/index.html?lang=en) because I forgot to set the `name servers` from `AWS Route 53` to `Freenom`.

**Name servers from AWS Route 53:**

[image]

*(`ns` means `name server`)

**Set the name servers above to Freenom:**

[image]

Then, it was validated from pending. However, even if I set name servers to `Freenom`, it sometimes takes a forever time to be validated. In this case, I delete the request and make a new request a few hours later again, then, it is validated properly.

Optionally saying, we registered the domains at the domain providers like `GoDaddy`, `Namecheap`, `Freenow` and so on, then, we need to set the `name servers` from `AWS Route 53` to `GoDaddy`, `Namecheap`, `Freenow` and so on. Finally, our domains will be validated from `AWS Certificate Manager`.

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same solution as @Kai - had to add the NS records to the primary domain.  But my situation was a little bit different:

- I'm using AWS Route53 for my domains
- with the root domain (example.com.au) in a different AWS account
- and a subdomain (subdomain.example.com.au) in the account where I'm creating the certificate
- Because it's all within AWS I could just click the "create record in Route 53" button to get the verification record automatically added... but the certificate would not resolve
- THE PROBLEM : the subdomain was not resolving through to the root domain
- HOW I FOUND IT : `dig +trace subdomain.example.com.au`
- - that SHOULD return a string of responses from `.` then `au.` then `com.au.` then `example.com.au.` and finally `subdomain.example.com.au.`
- - it did not return the subdomain record, which was the clue that the link between the subdomain and the root domain was not correct.
- adding the NS records from the subdomain as a CNAME record on the root domain (similar to Kai's answer) caused the validation to complete almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

That is my api gw with cloudflare! It works already.

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32449918)