# AWS Certificate Request Validation Timeout

Tags: amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

I'm trying to request a certificate using AWS certificate manager. I'm using route53 for DNS. I go through all of the steps, and use the "create record in Route53" to create the CNAME record automatically. I have double checked the CNAME record in Route53 to make sure it is the same one that ACM expects. After doing all of this, the DNS validation times out.

I have tried this multiple times with the same result. I barely know how to use `dig` so I'm kind of lost on how to troubleshoot this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I switched my domain from godaddy to AWS, the Name Server records did not automatically update. I thought they would but I actually had to change them manually from the AWS console.

Comment: Can you describe how you found the correct Amazon DNS record? For those of us who may be having the same problem?

Answer (score 4):

I had registered a domain with Route 53 and was facing a similar issue when I deleted my website's hosted zone.

The `CNAME` record in Route 53 was exactly as it was in ACM (no extra strings, whitespaces, etc.)

The issue was in Route 53 - the name servers associated with the registered domain were different from the name servers associated with the hosted zone.

I fixed this issue by:-

1. Deleting and re-creating the hosted zone.
2. **Replacing the NS values in the registered domain with the NS values of from the newly created hosted zone.**
3. Creating a certificate in Certificate Manager with the domain name matching with the one specified in Route 53 hosted zone.
4. Creating a Route 53 record from the Certificate manager wizard (which is step 5 in the wizard)

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, I registered a domain through route53 and then created a hosted zone but the name servers were all different between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue, where i copied the whole "name" of the CNAME record (from the AWS certificate manager) to the DNS configuration for my domain. And waited a whole day without any success. Then after reading "Michael - sqlbot" answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53166438/certificate-in-pending-state-in-aws-certificate-manager), i removed the `.example.com` from `_9022ecb910c52234234234234232xxxx.example.com` in my domain's DNS configuration and Amazon Certificate Manager issued the certificate in about next 30 mins.

Hope you are not making the same mistake :-)

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply. I'm using the "Create Record in Route53" button after creating the certificate, so AWS creates the record for me. I double checked and it's not using .example.com. I tried using dig to troubleshoot and I'm getting this response for querying the CNAME record (and A record for that matter)```id 60031
opcode QUERY
rcode SERVFAIL
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
maxpaymar.com. IN CNAME
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL```

Comment: I am not an expert in using Dig, but there are two things, that indicate a problem, that i can see in the response you get from Dig.

1. `rcode SERVFAIL`  - i get `rcode NOERROR`

2. `;QUESTION maxpaymar.com. IN CNAME ; ANSWER <blank>` 

Whereas what i get is..
`;QUESTION
www.mydomain.com. IN CNAME
;ANSWER
www.mydomain.com. 3599 IN CNAME d2xxw7xx19mpsi.cloudfront.net.`