# Create aws certification for domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, certificate, aws-route53

small question, maybe you could help me. I'm trying to create a certificate for a domain that I transferred to AWS a few days ago. I saw the CNAME Record below, copied it, and pasted it in the domain records, omitting the suffix (domain name) because it automatically adds the suffix in the records form, and this was done yesterday and it's still pending. Besides, today I also saw a button that creates the record, so I tried clicking it. Several hours have passed and the certificate is still not created. I want to make sure I'm doing everything right. If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it. I suppose I'm missing some small finish?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53166438/certificate-in-pending-state-in-aws-certificate-manager)

Comment: the problem was old values on nameserver the cause interuption with the creation of the certificate